# Run django test parallel with in memory sqlite3

Tags: python, django, testing, sqlite, parallel-processing

Is it possible to run django test cases in parallel with in memory sqlite3 with new database for each test case?

Docs says: "--parallel" Runs tests in separate parallel processes. Each process gets its own database.

```
# *settings_test.py
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
```

When I run my test in single process, all goes well.

```
python.exe manage.py test --settings=gbook.settings_test
```

When i use --parallel param, DiscoverRunner.setup_databases **called only one time**.

```
python.exe manage.py test --settings=gbook.settings_test --parallel=4
```

In result i reseive this:

```
OperationalError("Problem installing fixture ...AirportInfo.json': Could not load order.AirportInfo(pk=2411): no such table: GB_AIRPORT_INFO",)
```

Please, help me to understand, what am i doing wrong.

multiprocessing.cpu_count() = 4

Django version 1.11.10

Python 3.6.5

Comment: So, what is the actual problem?

Comment: edited*, also this is same my question with details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147008/django-test-parallel-appregistrynotready

Comment: It might be worth noting that the [docs on --parallel] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-parallel) say "This feature isn’t available on Windows."

Comment: I saw it, but I thought it was about stdlib library =(